# DIV Table with rows and columns

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm making a DIV table but the last two rows which contain colums don't show a border.
Does somebody know a workarround?

Here is my code:

CSS

```
.contentwrap {  width: 300px;   display: table; }   
.contentwrap .box-row {display: table-row;} 
.contentwrap .box { padding: 15px;  display: table-cell; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }   
.contentwrap .box-column { display: table-row; }
.contentwrap .column { padding: 15px; display: table-cell; width: 10%; border-color: #e5e5e5; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="contentwrap">
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box">row 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box">row 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box">rpw 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box">row 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
      <div class="box-column">
        <div class="col">column1</div>
        <div class="col">column2</div>
        <div class="col">column3</div>
        <div class="col">column4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-column">
        <div class="col">column1</div>
        <div class="col">column2</div>
        <div class="col">column3</div>
        <div class="col">column4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't apply a border to the last two groups of divs. Only your box class has a border.

Comment: also you're declaring the class .column but in your code you're using .col

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLagppnb/1/) with your code.

Comment: Thanks all for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the effect you want, but I just changed 
`border-color: #e5e5e5;` in `.contentwrap .column` to `border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;`

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eLagppnb/2/)

```
.contentwrap .col 
{ 
    padding: 15px; 
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 10%; 
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5 
}
```

Also you might want to check your namings, in your html you are using `col` but your css is using `column`. I changed it to `col` for you here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, the following modifications to your CSS should do the trick.

```
.box-column { display: table-row; } 
.col{ padding: 15px; display: table-cell; width: 10%; border-color: #e5e5e5; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
```